# Jenkins:Sending mail notification only when projects get 10 times consecutive failures

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-mailer-plugin

I added mail and editable mail notifications on the project.As I said it in the title.I just want to get a mail,if only project gets consecutively 10 times failure.I added unstable trigger on editable mail but couldn't get what I want.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it after a while digging on the internet.We should add File X trigger on advanced tab.After that we can set number of failures.